# Manage multiple test environments

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jira

I need some help trying to make my lab tests better!

Where I work every team has one server to test new features and bug fixes.
Then, each server is divided in slots. When a new feature is done, the Programmer needs to check if there is some available slot to deploy the software. If the is no slot available, the Programmer needs to create another slot!

My question is: is there any software that helps the programmers to manage the available environments? That tells me wich slot is available and with feature is benigno tested in each slot?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in a similar scenario and I'm collecting ideas at the moment.